# Function over non-numerical sets

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Considering a finite lexicographically ordered set, for example, $\{a, b, c, d\}$ called $A$ with $A$ as domain and codomain of a function which returns the element with right shift of 1 over A, how can this be written according to Mathematics standards?

I have in mind something like that:

$f: A \to A, f(s) = \operatorname{shift}(s, 1)$

So $f(a)=b, f(b)=c, \ldots, f(d) = a$

This also leads me to another question: How to get the index of an element
by it in an ordered set? I mean for example $A(a)=1, A(b)=2, \ldots$

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are looking for notation. In this case, you do not have to define a new set, but can simply use $ Z_4 $. Then simply, $ \mathrm{shift}(a, b) = a + b $.

Comment: Thanks for answering, @M.Fisher. Usually we learn functions over numerical domains and binary operations such as addition f(a, b) = a + b. But it is still unclear to me whether I can simply cite operator Shift(a,b) in a Math article, without define explicity this operation in algebraic sense before.